# If /Else statement on JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get this problem to work. It works fine if I remove the else statement like here:

```js
function isRank (string){
    string = string.toLowerCase();
  var valid = ['two','three','four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine','ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
  //var checkIt = string.toLowerCase();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
    
    if (string === valid[i])
      return true;
    } 
}

console.log(isRank('SIX'));
```

but if I add the else statement, like here it only returns false....what gives?

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/deyocuwayu/edit?js,console)

Comment: There is no `else` in the code.

Comment: replace the body of the function with one line `return ['two','three','four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine','ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'].indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0;`  ... or ... `return ~['two','three','four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine','ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'].indexOf(string.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return false after the `for` loop:

```
function isRank (string){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var valid = ['two','three','four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine','ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
  //var checkIt = string.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
    if (string === valid[i]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(isRank('SIX'));
```

Just for fun, a simplified version:

```
function isRank(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var valid = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
  return !!~valid.indexOf(string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks TbWill, that worked....

Answer (score 2):

If I follow the quite obvious logic:

```
function isRank(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var valid = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight',
  'nine', 'ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
  //var checkIt = string.toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
    if (string === valid[i])
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

You return false if none fits, that is, after everything has been checked, that means after the loop.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to the question, instead of freaking out over a mis-indented bracket >_>

Comment: I think that comes with age ;-)

Comment: Thanks deamentiaemundi.... that did the trick too...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you keep getting false when you add the else statement is because when you return you exit the function. You can only return once. So when the for loop run it checks on the first value

```
if ('SIX' === 'two') {
  return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
```

So here it stops checking because you have returned false. The way to fix this is check if there is a match and if there is return true. if there is not just let the loop continue. And when the loop finishes running then you should return false because there was no match:

```
function isRank (string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var valid = ['two','three','four','five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine','ten', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];
  for (var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
    if (string === valid[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
 return false;
}
console.log(isRank('SIX'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no "else", but I'm going to take an educated guess that you wrote this:

```
if (string === valid[i])
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Or similar.

The problem is that `return` stops everything immediately. So unless the match is the very first item, you'll get "false" no matter what. Instead, you should just `return false;` *immediately after the loop* (outside it!), which loosely translates to "if we made it this far without `return true;`, then `return false;`".

Comment: Aside: the "bad" code above can be simplified to `return string === valid[i];` - no need to manually return true or false when testing a condition.